# SAML - intended destination endpoint does not match the recipient endpoint

Tags: saml

A client is trying to SSO into our app and the following error is thrown.

ERROR org.opensaml.common.binding.decoding.BaseSAMLMessageDecoder- SAML message intended destination endpoint 
'https://client.ourapp.com/product:445/ProductName/AssertionConsumer' did not match the recipient endpoint 
'https://client.ourapp.com/product:445/ProductName'

Notice the recipient endpoint is missing the '/AssertionConsumer'. Will appreciate if someone can guide on where I could be going wrong. Thanks

Comment: what is the SAML solution do you use? like ADFS or PingFed, or else?

Comment: Chenrui -  The issue was we had overridden the getActualReceiverEndpointURI() method in HTTPPostDecoder class. Fixing this method took care of the error.  Thanks for your response.